# R code to reproduce REDCap "Stats and Charts" report

Tags: r, redcap

Does anyone know if there is R code available to reproduce the "Stats and Charts" output created by REDCap for any given project?

For each question in a project, REDCap reiterates the question itself, provides a tally of responses (with missing values), the count/frequency of each response in the question (absolute and percentage), and a visual graphic based on the type of question (continuous, categorical)and the possible responses.

The "Stats and Charts" report is very handy. Building off this report would be very helpful rather than trying to recreate the report as a starting point.

I've looked into a few different respoitories, but no luck so far.

Comment: Can you explain REDCap?

Comment: REDCap is a secure web application for building and managing online surveys and databases. While REDCap can be used to collect virtually any type of data in any environment (including compliance with 21 CFR Part 11, FISMA, HIPAA, and GDPR), it is specifically geared to support online and offline data capture for research studies and operations.